# CDK BasePathMapping for existing custom domain is created but doesn't work

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

This is all done using CDK.

I created a REST API and custom domain associated with it via a base path mapping (`domain.addBasePathMapping()`). That worked fine.

Due to some requirement, I also need to redirect a particular path from another custom domain (I'll call this the old domain) to this api. In theory this should be straightforward - just create a base path mapping from the old domain to the new API.

This is how I tried doing it:

```js
const domain = DomainName.fromDomainNameAttributes(this, 'oldDomain', {
    domainName: 'the old custom domain name',
    domainNameAliasTarget: 'the "API Gateway domain name" value from the console for that domain',
    domainNameAliasHostedZoneId: 'the "Hosted zone ID" value from the console for that domain',
});
new BasePathMapping(this, 'myMapping', {
    domainName: domain,
    restApi: this.api,
    basePath: 'foo',
});
```

First I created a `DomainName` object by looking up the old domain, then created a mapping to my new API with some path. Note that I cannot call `addBasePathMapping()` on the domain name created, as that method returns an `IDomainName` which doesn't have that method.

When I ran this, it created the base path mapping in the old custom domain, pointing to my new api, correct stage, specified path. Great!

Except it didn't work. Invoking `[old domain]/foo/bar` (where `bar` is the resource path in the new API) returned 404.

The strange thing is that when I create that mapping manually via the console, it works perfectly.

Another weird thing is that if I create it via CDK, and then edit it in the console, it starts working. If I then delete it (manually or via CDK) and then create it again via CDK, it continues to work. But of course this isn't a proper solution.

I can only assume that creating it manually performs some extra operation not done via the CDK construct, but as the docs don't say what else may need to be done, I have no idea what.

Comment: Note you can post a self-answered question with both parts _at the same time_, rather than adding meta content into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the `CfnApiMapping` construct from `aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigatewayv2`. In fact this is a lot easier as you don't need to get the hosted zone id etc, just pass it some readily available information and it creates a base path mapping that actually works:

```js
new CfnApiMapping(this, 'myMapping', {
    apiId: this.api.restApiId,
    domainName: 'old custom domain'
    stage: this.api.deploymentStage.stageName,
    apiMappingKey: 'foo',
});
```

I should warn that this comes with strange behaviour.

First an overview of my setup:

The old api has the following path on it: `[old api]/foo/bar`. The old custom domain is mapped straight to the old api with no path, so the old endpoint url is `[old custom domain]/foo/bar`. The new endpoint is `[new custom domain]/bar`. In order for the old URL to map to the new api, I need a base path mapping for `foo` on the old custom domain to point to the new api, so that `[old custom domain]/foo/bar` will be directed to `[new api]/bar`. (Note there are no other resources on `foo` and nothing new will be added, so this is fine.)

So currently calling `[old custom domain]/foo/bar` invokes the `/foo/bar` path on the old api. Once I deploy the `CfnApiMapping` resource, calling that same URL invokes the correct path on the new api.

**Weird behaviour 1:** If I delete that base path mapping, I would expect it to go back to the original api. Instead I get a 403 error. If I create it again, it resolves to the new API again, and deleting it again gives the 403 error again.

**Weird behaviour 2:** If instead of deleting it, I change the path value so it no longer maps "foo", the `/foo/bar` path works with the old endpoint again. I can then delete the mapping and everything keeps working fine.

**Weird behaviour 3:** I am unable to recreate this as I can't remember which sequence of steps I took, but it happened a couple of times where I deleted the base path mapping and it continued to work as if the mapping was still there. There was no mapping visible in the console, and I gave it plenty of time for the change to take effect, but it continued to work.

All this is done with the CDK, not manually. Doing this manually or via regular cloudformation works with no issues.